# Validación DecimalField Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando crear una validación para un campo `DecimalField` en Django.

Probando en el shell:

```
>> from django.forms import DecimalField
>> from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
>> f = DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
>> f.validate(11) # se supone que luego deberia mostrar un error
>>
```

Pero no me muestra ningún error de validación luego de ejecutar validate. Se supone que debería mostrar un error porque el valor a validar es mayor que 10.

Que estoy haciendo mal o no tengo claro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para probar el validador usa el metodo `clean`. O si tienes un objeto de ese modelo puedes llamar a `full_clean`. Ejemplo:

```
>> f = DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
>> f.clean(9.9)
>> Decimal('9.9')
>> f.clean(10)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Ensure this value is less than or equal to 10.']
```

Por cierto, el argumento `max_digits` incluye los decimales, es decir que si tienes `max_digits=2` mostraría un error con `10.1`.

Saludos. Espero haberte ayudado.